# Convert polyshape to set of coordinates array

Tags: matlab, polygon

I wish to find the shortest distance between a point and a `polyshape` using the `distancepointpolygon` function from Matlab [`geom2d` library](https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/7844-geom2d).
The `distancepointpolygon` function does it for polygon and therefore how can I convert any `polyshape` to a N-by-2 array containing vertex coordinates? I did it manually and I am looking for a general solution.

```
polySquare = polyshape([0 5 5 0], [10 10 15 15]);
plot(polySquare)
square = [0 10; 5 10; 5 15; 0 15];
p0 = [5 10];
distancePointPolygon(p0, square)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`polySquare.Vertices` should be the matrix you need:

```matlab
>> polySquare = polyshape([0 5 5 0],[10 10 15 15]);
>> polySquare.Vertices

ans =

     0    10
     0    15
     5    15
     5    10
```

Thus you can do:

```matlab
polySquare = polyshape([0 5 5 0], [10 10 15 15]);
plot(polySquare)
square = polySquare.Vertices;
p0 = [5 10];
distancePointPolygon(p0, square)
```

See [the documentation](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/polyshape.html).

Comment: I second this ^ . Also, gotta ask, what is your profile pic? It's too cool not to ask, @Cris.

Comment: Thanks. How can I convert it to this fromat [x1 y1; x2 y2; xn yn]?

Comment: @alirazi: I've added more details to the answer. Does this clarify things?

Comment: @Genoc: It's a tissue section, stained and imaged in a microscope. I've added the dark ring so it looks like you're looking through a microscope, and a letter C for my name. Just something different. :)